# Utilizando um hashMap

Tags: java

Tenho um hashMap e dentro dele eu tenho uma ArrayList.

Como eu faço para saber se um elemento tem nessa list através do hashMap?

```
List<Carteira> carteiras = ArrayList<Carteira>();
carteiras.add(carteira1);
carteiras.add(carteira2);

Map<String, Carteira> filter = HashMap<String, Carteira>();
filter.put("carteiras", carteiras)

buscarCarteiras(filter);
```

---

Outra classe...

```
buscarCarteiras(Map<String,Carteira> param){
    //Como faço para pegar o objeto carteira1

}
```

Comment: Você pode explicar melhor, com um exemplo em código? Aliás, o código é Java ou C#?!

Comment: O código é em java. Vou tentar explanar melhor a minha dúvida.

Comment: 1) seu código compila? acredito que não, pois aqui `filter.put("carteiras", carteiras)` vc está tentando colocar uma lista de carteiras onde deveria ser um objeto Carteira, ou a declaração do Map deveria ter sido `Map<String, List<Carteira>> filter = new HashMap<>();` 2) que outra classe? como vc pretende chamar um método de outra classe? 3) `Como faço para pegar o objeto carteira1` qual critério voce deseja usar para saber qual elemento voce quer pegar? talvez voce queira passar o objeto carteira como argumento para o método `buscarCarteira()` tb?

Comment: eu ja conseguir passa como parâmetro a lista dentro do map e já conseguir chegar no método, está vindo os valores corretamente, só que eu quero saber como faço para acessar cada elemento daquela lista que ta no map.

Comment: `param.get("carteiras").containsKey(carteira1)`

Comment: essa é minha dúvida, eu não sei pegar o valor dentro daquela listar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Respondendo a pergunta:

> quero saber como faço para acessar cada elemento daquela lista que ta no map

Você deve fazer dois loops, um que percorrar todos os elementos do seu Map e outro que percorra todos os elementos do List, que está dentro do seu Map.

Criei um exemplo compilável que demonstra algo similar à sua pergunta original e respondendo sua pergunta que está no comentário:

```
import java.util.*;

class Carteira {
    private int num;
    public void setNum(int num) { this.num = num; }
    public int getNum() { return this.num; }
    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Valor da carteira: " + num; }
}

public class TesteHash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Carteira>> filter = new HashMap<>();
        List<Carteira> carteiras = new ArrayList<>();
        Carteira carteira1 = new Carteira();
        Carteira carteira2 = new Carteira();

        carteira1.setNum(10);
        carteira2.setNum(15);
        carteiras.add(carteira1);
        carteiras.add(carteira2);
        filter.put("carteiras", carteiras);

        buscarCarteiras(filter);
    }

    public static void buscarCarteiras(Map<String, List<Carteira>> param) {
        //aqui responde a sua dúvida
        for(Map.Entry<String, List<Carteira>> entry: param.entrySet()) { 
            for(Carteira c: entry.getValue()) {
                //na variavel `c` vc tem um objeto carteira
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note que o primeiro `for` só executará uma única vez, pois dentro da variável `param` tem apenas um par de valores `"carteiras"`, `carteiras`.

O segundo `for` será executado duas vezes, pois ele percorre toda a lista que está dentro do Map, e dentro dessa lista possui dois objetos do tipo `Carteira`. Dentro desse for ele imprimirá o valor que retorna do método `toString()` da classe `Carteira`.

Comment: Eu pensava que existia algum método da propriedade do map que fazia isso. E eu fiz isso isso só que foi com dois arraylist um dentro do outro. Se não tivesse essa propriedade eu ja e a fazer isso, mais foi bom vc me esclarecer, vlw muito!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.teste.apl;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Map<Integer, String> mapaNomeClientes = new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        mapaNomeClientes.put(1, "Willian Marques");
        mapaNomeClientes.put(2, "Antonio Dias");
        mapaNomeClientes.put(3, "Ortiz");
        mapaNomeClientes.put(1, "Teste");

        System.out.println(pesquisar());

    }
    private static String pesquisar(){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Informe a key");
        Integer key = entrada.nextInt();
        if(mapaNomeClientes.containsKey(key)){
            return String.valueOf(mapaNomeClientes.get(key));
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Então...

Algum campo dentro do Objeto Carteiras que seja único?

Porque criar uma lista e adicionar em um map? não dava para adicionar direto em um map
EX

```
Map<String,Carteiras> mapa=new HashMap<>();

    Carteira carteira=new Carteira();

    // setar campos
    mapa.put(carteira.getId(),carteira);

    if(mapa.containskey("00X1")) {
        /// get da carteira
    }
```

Porque não utilizar o lambda com java e List

```
List<RealVar> lista=new ArrayList<>();

    Optional<RealVar> optional=lista.stream().filter(x->x.getId()==19).findFirst();

    if(optional.isPresent()) {
        // faça o que Precisa
    }
```